# Word add-in installation for Mac OS and Windows

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have a javascript add-in developed for Word which I now wish to deploy for other users to download and install on their Mac/Windows Word. All the instructions I can find for this indicate that it is possible to deploy on a non-azure etc. web server. I've modified manifest.xml so that all previous references to localhost:3000 now point to the download site. e.g.
"https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"
becomes:
"https://example.com/office/word/taskpane.html"

I've run
npm run build
with the new manifest.xml and the dist folder is populated – these files I FTP to:
https://example.com/office/word/

Assuming all has gone well with the above and I have not missed anything out, I now have the issue of how to import that add-in into Word (not side-loaded but from https://example.com/office/word/).

I'm using Word for Mac v.16.46. In the Insert ribbon, neither of the two buttons managing add-ins presents any way to input https://example.com/office/word/ or similar.

Any ideas how I (and my users) import the add-in into Word (MacOS/Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit manifest to App Source on Office Store, So, you can dowload and use it.
Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center

Else, other way of doing this is deploy add-in at central location via admin center. It will allow to access add-in for specific peoples(To whom, you will provide access.
Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment

For other ways, you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish

Comment: Thanks for the response Vikas. I got the impression reading all the docs.microsoft.com stuff that it was possible to host the add-in anywhere. Here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/host-an-office-add-in-on-microsoft-azure it states: "You can host the web app of an Office Add-in on any web hosting platform, including Azure." 'Any web hosting platform' i.e. mine is what I'm seeking but I cannot find anything at all about it. I just want to be able to make available the manifest.xml which links to the add-in files on my web server.

It seems this is not possible . . .

Comment: @MarkGrimshaw-Aagaard Did you figure out how to use your own hosting?